# Showing that a complex function is constant

Tags: complex-analysis

The question is:
Let $f:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be analytic and $\Omega$ be a domain in $\mathbb{C}$.  Prove that if there exists $c\in\mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)=\overline{cf(z)}$ for every $z\in\Omega$, then $f$ is a constant function.

my thoughts: Since $f$ is analytic, $f$ must satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations.  So, if we let $f(z)=u+iv$ then $f(z)=\overline{cf(z)}=cu-civ$.  Then, $\frac{du}{dx}=\frac{dv}{dy}$ and $\frac{du}{dy}=-\frac{dv}{dx}$.  But, we must also have that $\frac{du}{dx}=-\frac{dv}{dy}$ and $\frac{cdu}{dy}=\frac{cdv}{dx}$.  So, I'm assuming that we are just playing a game with setting different parts of the CR equations equal to other parts based on the $f(z)=\overline{cf(z)}$, but I just can't seem to get it to come out clean.  Any help would be very much appreciated :)

Comment: Presumably you mean for every $z \in \Omega$, not $\mathbb C$, since $f$ is only defined in $\Omega$.

Comment: wlog $c \ne 0$ so then $cf^2(z)=|cf(z)|^2 \ge 0$; but a nonconstant analytic function is open, so $cf^2$ constant and hence $f$ takes at most two values but by continuity, it is constant since $\Omega$ is connected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $f$ in non zero, then we see that $|c| = 1$, so we can let $c=e^{i \theta}$. Let $a=e^{i {\theta \over 2}}$ then $a f = \overline{af}$ and so
$g= af$ is analytic on $\Omega$ and real valued, hence by the open mapping theorem we see that it is constant.

Comment: I believe that this answer, combined with @Conrad comment was perfect :)  
Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to play the game with C-R, here is a way.

The case $c=0$ being trivial, assume $c=\alpha+i\beta \neq 0$, where $\alpha,\beta$ are real constants. Then by assumptions, one has $$u+i v=(\alpha u-\beta v)-i (\alpha v+\beta u).\quad (1)$$ Applying C-R to the RHS of (1), one has
$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}\alpha u_x-\beta v_x=-(\alpha v_y+\beta u_y)\\ \alpha u_y-\beta v_y=\alpha v_x+\beta u_x.\end{array}\right.\quad (2)$$ Applying C-R to LHS of (1), the system in (2) becomes $$\left\{\begin{array}{c}\alpha u_x-\beta v_x=-(\alpha u_x-\beta v_x)\\ -\alpha v_x-\beta u_x=\alpha v_x+\beta u_x.\end{array}\right.$$ which implies
$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}\alpha u_x=\beta v_x\\ \alpha v_x=-\beta u_x.\end{array}
\right.\quad (3)$$

From (3), one has $$\beta^2 v_x=\beta(\beta v_x)=\beta(\alpha u_x)=\alpha(\beta u_x)=\alpha(-\alpha v_x)$$
$$\Rightarrow (\alpha^2+\beta^2)v_x=0.$$ Similarly $$(\alpha^2+\beta^2)u_x=0.$$ Since $\alpha^2+\beta^2=|c|^2\neq 0,$ one has $$u_x=v_x=0$$ and by C-R, $$v_y=u_y=0$$ as well. This shows that $u,v$, hence $f$ is constant. QED

Comment: I'm glad to see that this was possible using what I was trying to use.  Thank you so much!!!